# PHP: array_splice() not giving me correct output

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, push, array-splice

I'm trying to experiment with array_splice and I get an output like this (from $match)

```
Array
(
    [Keep me Updated] => Array
        (
            [winner] => winnerl.jpg
            [0] => value0.jpg
        )

    [0] => valuel.jpg //this should really be inside [Leep me Updated] array
    [1] => value2.jpg //this should really be inside [Leep me Updated] array
    [2] => value3.jpg //this should really be inside [Leep me Updated] array
}
```

from (this foreach creates puts in the values into $match)

```
foreach($data as $d)
{
    if (isset($match[$d['data']['name']])) {
        $match_loser = array($d['loser']['lrg_img']);

        array_splice($match,1,0,$match_loser);
    }else{
        $match[$d['data']['name']] = array("winner"=>$d['winner']['lrg_img'],
                                            $d['loser']['lrg_img']);        
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to get is bring `[0],[1],[2]` into the `[Keep me Updated]` $match array:

```
Array
(
    [Keep me Updated] => Array
        (
            [winner] => winnerl.jpg
            [0] => value0.jpg
            [1] => value1.jpg   // old one: [0] => valuel.jpg
            [2] => value2.jpg   // old one: [1] => value2.jpg
            [3] => value3.jpg   // old one: [2] => value3.jpg
        )
}
```

This is what $data looks like

```
    $data[] = array(
    "data"=>array
    (
        "name"=>$name,
    ),
    "winner"=>array
    (
        "lrg_img"=>$img_url_winner
    ),      
    "loser"=>array
    (
        "lrg_img"=>$img_url_loser
    )
```

$data has array values, and $match is where I'm trying to sort the data. So if my values match, it'll consolidate.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual output?

Comment: @Asad sorry didn't make myself clear. The actual output is the first code, the values are going outside of the array I want to put into

Comment: Alright, but what is the purpose of having a single array inside an array?

Comment: @Asad there's more to it, but this is just the premise of the code I'm trying to figure out how to fix.

Comment: Try turning `$match[$d['data']['name']]` into `$match['Keep me Updated'][$d['data']['name']]`. Also, please post the values for `$name` etcetera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inner array as the argument to `array_splice`

```
foreach($data as $d)
{
    if (isset($match[$d['data']['name']])) {
        $match_loser = array($d['loser']['lrg_img']);

        array_splice($match[$d['data']['name']],1,0,$match_loser);
    }else{
        $match[$d['data']['name']] = array("winner"=>$d['winner']['lrg_img'],
                                            $d['loser']['lrg_img']);        
    }
}
```